# Check single row checkboxlist

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

i create a table row will auto generate data from sql and bound in by backend code.
Is it a way check that user has click or not by using javascript?
The row is create as below:

```
<tr>
    <td align="right" class="formLine">Brand Type:</td>
    <td class="FormLine2" align="left" colspan="7">
        <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkBrandType" runat="server" RepeatColumns="10" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Flow" BorderWidth="0" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Jquery solution

```
//assuming all your html elemnts and checkboxes are having unique ids
$("#check1").on('click', function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
        alert("checked");
    else {
        alert("unchecked");
    }
}
```

Otherwise if you just want to check if ANY checkbox has been clicked

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        alert('checked');
    } else {
        alert('unchecked');
    }
});
```

Comment: you idea is checking the whole table, i only have one row have checkbox and it like than option checkbox for user to click

Comment: @AndrewMadMan The first part of the answer checks the specified checkbox and not ALL.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done easily with the function below. Note the use of `CheckBoxList1.ClientID` to get the correct ID. Also you need to add `input` to the listener since asp.net will create a table around the checkboxes.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%= CheckBoxList1.ClientID %> input").change(function (e) {
            if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
                alert($(this).val());
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: the data bind with the checkbox by execute the sql query from the backend code and bind them using
 DataTextField  is for brandname and  DataValueField is for brandid

Comment: Then I'm not understanding your question. You want to check on PostBack if a CheckBox is checked?

Comment: if set an postback will it effect others row, in this table i devided the table into three part for periority of user to fill in some of the textbox in the table

Comment: Then my function will do the trick. It does not matter how the checkboxes are filled from code behind.

Comment: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #<%= chkBrandType.ClientID %> input

Comment: For `<%= CheckBoxList1.ClientID %>` to work you need to place it on the aspx page.

Comment: i need to place it in js file.

Comment: Get it working first. Then solve the next problem of having it in a js. And you can also bind the listener on class name instead of ID

Comment: need to find a way to solve this first http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43911365/bind-gridview-data-to-dropdownlist